# Gmail Web Login Dark Mode

Tags: gmail

I'm looking for Gmail web login dark mode. Currently when you go to login to Gmail it is a white background. This is **before** you login so applying a dark theme cannot help me here. (FYI: I am using Firefox browser) Is there a Gmail web login **DARK** web page available ?